# Get Visitors Name from Logged In Social Networks

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, google-plus, social-networking

I have been reading this post http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/detect-visitor-social-networks/ about detecting whether a user is signed in to a social network, and was just wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to display a users name using the social networks API?

The functionality would be for a welcome message to a website, and a fallback would create a generalised message if a first name could not be determined. I'm not even looking to log them in to the website, just grab a first name.

I have built quite a few sites where a user must confirm with facebook that they are sharing their information with my website before I can grab any data, but I'm wondering if anyone has seen any situations where you are able to just grab a first name without needing confirmation from the user?

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this?

[How get public information of a user in facebook without requesting for his/her permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706506/how-get-public-information-of-a-user-in-facebook-without-requesting-for-his-her)

According to the answer, you can get public Facebook data with just an app token.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: this is not possible without the user signing in through the Facebook API.

Comment: Yeah that's my experience with it. I just wondered if anyone had seen anything different.